# Acessing Data in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I've read over documentation and tutorials over NHibernate but I don't understand how to actually manipulate data in the database. My setup is NHibernate 2.1 and an Oracle database.

When I want to manipulate or read data from the database do I use Get/Load to load an entity with the data I want or do I have to use Criteria to query the database first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen chapter 9 of the NHibernate Reference, [Manipulating Data](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/manipulatingdata.html)? It has short pointers on the different aspects. As for `Get()` or querying, if you know the identifier you would normally use `Get()` or `Load()`, otherwise you use any of querying APIs.

Here is an example using Load(). Inside an open session and transaction you would do this:

```
DomesticCat cat = (DomesticCat) sess.Load<Cat>( 69L );
cat.Name = "PK";
sess.Flush();  // changes to cat are automatically detected and persisted
               // Flush not required if FlushMode is Commit or Auto (and
               // transactions are used, which you should).
```

Note also that NHibernate 2.1 is very old. Consider using a newer version, but at least be aware that some things mentioned in the current documentation isn't available in such an old version.

Comment: I understand 2.1 is very old but my codebase requires I use .Net 2.0
Thanks for your answer!